# Direct PHP file error message if they access it directly

Tags: php

i have a php file called "Status.php" which basically allows the person if they use the correct URL

`http://konvictgaming.com/status.php?channel=isypie` to pull their twitch.tv stream online/offline status, That works perfectly

However i would like it so that if they attempt to access the status.php file directly
http://konvictgaming.com/status.php
It will return the error

ERROR: Please put a stream user in your link.
ex: `http://konvictgaming.com/status.php?channel=konvictgaming`

my current code

```
<?php

$channelName = htmlspecialchars($_GET['channel'], ENT_QUOTES);

$clientId = '';             // Register your application and get a client ID at http://www.twitch.tv/settings?section=applications
$online = 'online.png';     // Set online image here
$offline = 'offline.png';   // Set offline image here
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.strtolower($channelName).'?client_id='.$clientId), true);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
$image = null;
if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {
    $channelTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name'];
    $streamTitle = $json_array['stream']['channel']['status'];
    $currentGame = $json_array['stream']['channel']['game'];

    $image = file_get_contents($online);
} else {
    $image = file_get_contents($offline);        
}
echo $image;

?>
```

Comment: Please post the code here, not in pastebin.

Comment: I tried Multiple times, it refuses to let me & gives me the Indent by 4 Message

Comment: `if (!isset($_GET['channel']))` anyone?

Comment: Also, why are you HTML-escaping a value which has nothing to do with HTML?

Comment: @deceze Im pulling the PHP file into a HTML template as the CMS i use is HTML based & to get the images to show i had to do that =)

Comment: In this particular piece of code you're not using the value in any HTML context. Even if you did later: escape at the point of inserting into HTML, not before! You're also using the value in a URL where HTML entities are misplaced and where the value needs to be urlencoded instead!

Answer (score 2):

Just add a check at the beginning of your script:

```
if(empty($_GET['channel']))
    die('ERROR: Please put a stream user in your link. ex: http://konvictgaming.com/status.php?channel=konvictgaming');
```

Comment: Will do mate, just waiting for the Timer to count down xD!